# visual studio team services load test is not using new machines in load balancer

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, load-testing

we have an azure web application, configured with auto-scaling. and we are load-testing it using Visual Studio Team Services. autoscaling is working fine and it kicks in at one moment, however our load test users remain on original (first two maschines in load-balancer-cluster) which are chocking under load and cpu usage of 100%  and the new machines  do not get any request.

We assume that TCP connections from load-agents are sticking to this first two  machines and new machines are simply ignored by our tests. Is there a way to tell load tests in cloud to re-establish TCP connection so that new servers can also be utilised ?

this are the config settings we were using:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8CmpwlrdSs0cjdUMkdWbGV2QjQ/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8CmpwlrdSs0QlQ4R3JpNnJ3Mkk/view?usp=sharing

almir

Comment: What're steps that you did? (Include metrics setting)

Comment: I have added links to our settings, I hope this is what you were looking for if not, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "Use Multiple IPs" to "false" in your loadtest settings.

Comment: we will run it now, but I believe we had it like that initially and it did not work, than we changed it to this one

Comment: hi we rerun the tests but it remained as it was. however we recevied the message "This load test will run using 5 Internet Protocol (IP) addresses." should we open ticket ?

Comment: @zebra That's weird. I tried with the loadtest setting you provided, it works at my side after changing "Use Multiple IPs" to "false". To narrow down the issue, can you try create a new Azure WebApp but do not deploy any web app into it. And then run the loadtest to check the behavior?